# How can I deploy a web app to interect with hyperledger fabric v1.4?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have the chaincode (go) and first-network codes. But now I need a web app.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a "Hyperledger Fabric Client SDK" to use APIs to interact with a Hyperledger Fabric blockchain.
Look at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node.

You can find sample node js client apps in

```
fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript-low-level
```

at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples